# Email is already taken only if account is validated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I would like to overide the action thats says: 'Email is already taken' in Devise

I'm building an app where the user can invite someone to multiple items (todo, events, folder, etc ...) through his email. To avoid a multiplications of invitations tables and improve scalability. My idea was to create a user with only an email. This allows all users of the application to refer to a unique user (through his email) even if he is not registered. Instead of multiplying the invitations elements. 
However, the basic 'Devise' configuration does not allow this organization.
I would like to redo this step of registration.

This is what I want to do :

```
if this mail was already been taken
  if the account related has already confirmed his email
    notice = 'Email is already taken'
  else 
    send a confirmation on the mail
  end 
else
  Create User
end
```

I've already consulted the gem [Devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable), but it's not exactly what I want to do.

Has anyone ever tried to do this? If yes, how ?

Comment: Devise is not set up to do this and I wouldn't recommend this approach. Why would you send a confirmation email to someone who has not signed up themself?  There you need to just send an invitation and set up the normal sign-up process.  You might be better off using a seperate model like `GuestUser` or `InvitedUser` who's data structure might contain a unique email address.  It's still unclear what you're trying to do.  Can you post some code from your application that's actually working?

Comment: Hi @lacostenycoder, first thanks for your response. I have to reformulate what I'm trying to do. To improve the performance of my app, I would like to have a uniq table User. Which is referencing all the link (invitation, access, etc...). So if a user invite someone with his mail, it will be link to a user. To avoid data not found, if the user is not into our db, he will be created (with only a mail). And if this particular user want to register latter, he will already have all the information related to his account.

Comment: If this is a Ruby question then you should convert that to actual Ruby code, not just a sketch of what you'd like the gnomes to deliver to you in working form.

Comment: It's to explain it more clearly, I know how to do it. My question is about the way to achieve this method

Comment: @tadman it looks like this `%w(this mail was already been taken).each { |n| define_method(n) {|arg=nil| (arg ||= [true,false].sample) && [true,false].sample }}`